# Parsing Flat Inventory From Inventory API File With Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need your help to understand or find the best way to parse a string like this from inventories API  who return this:

> ""Name","Status","Environnement",\r\n
> "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
> "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
> "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
> "srvin-host10","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
> "srvin-host2","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
> "srvin-host2","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
> "srvin-host3","Active","PRODUCTION""

I would like to make an inventory file with servername and group as environment, but I don't know how to proceed, maybe python script, but I am new to python...

```yaml
  - name: Display Variable
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ var2.0 }}-{{ var2.1 }}-{{ var2.2 }}"

  - name: Creating a Dictionary in a Task 
    set_fact:
        userdata: "{{ userdata | default({}) |
                      combine ({ item.key : item.value }) }}"
    with_items:
      - { 'key': 'Name' , 'value': '{{ var2.0 }}'}
      - { 'key': 'Status' , 'value': '{{ var2.1 }}'}
      - { 'key': 'Environment' , 'value': '{{ var2.2 }}'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the data

```yaml
    userdata: >-
      "Name","Status","Environnement",\r\n
      "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host10","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host2","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host2","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host3","Active","PRODUCTION"
```

Split the lines (fit the pipe to your needs)

```yaml
  crlf: ',\r\n'
  dquote: '"'
  nothing: ''
  userdata_lines: "{{ userdata|replace(dquote, nothing)|
                               split(crlf)|
                               map('trim')|
                               map('split', ',') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  userdata_lines:
    - [Name, Status, Environnement]
    - [srvin-host1, Active, PRODUCTION]
    - [srvin-host1, Active, PRODUCTION]
    - [srvin-host1, Active, PRODUCTION]
    - [srvin-host10, Active, PRODUCTION]
    - [srvin-host2, Active, PRODUCTION]
    - [srvin-host2, Active, PRODUCTION]
    - [srvin-host3, Active, PRODUCTION]
```

Create [dictionaries](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_abstract_informations_dictionaries.html#dictionaries)

```yaml
  userdata_dicts: "{{ userdata_lines[1:]|map('zip', userdata_lines.0)|
                                         map('map', 'reverse')|
                                         map('community.general.dict') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  userdata_dicts:
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host1, Status: Active}
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host1, Status: Active}
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host1, Status: Active}
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host10, Status: Active}
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host2, Status: Active}
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host2, Status: Active}
    - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host3, Status: Active}
```

If you want to create groups by `Environnement` use the filter [groupby](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.groupby)

```yaml
  userdata_groups: "{{ userdata_dicts|groupby('Environnement') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  userdata_groups:
    - - PRODUCTION
      - - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host1, Status: Active}
        - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host1, Status: Active}
        - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host1, Status: Active}
        - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host10, Status: Active}
        - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host2, Status: Active}
        - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host2, Status: Active}
        - {Environnement: PRODUCTION, Name: srvin-host3, Status: Active}
```

Create and test the template

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for group in userdata_groups %}
          [{{ group.0 }}]
          {% for host in group.1|json_query(query)|unique %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        query: '[?Status == `Active`].Name'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    [PRODUCTION]
    srvin-host1
    srvin-host10
    srvin-host2
    srvin-host3
```

Write the file if this is what you want

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/hosts
        content: |
          {% for group in userdata_groups %}
          [{{ group.0 }}]
          {% for host in group.1|json_query(query)|unique %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        query: '[?Status == `Active`].Name'
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

will create the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/hosts
[PRODUCTION]
srvin-host1
srvin-host10
srvin-host2
srvin-host3
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    userdata: >-
      "Name","Status","Environnement",\r\n
      "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host1","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host10","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host2","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host2","Active","PRODUCTION",\r\n
      "srvin-host3","Active","PRODUCTION"

    crlf: ',\r\n'
    dquote: '"'
    nothing: ''
    userdata_lines: "{{ userdata|replace(dquote, nothing)|
                                 split(crlf)|
                                 map('trim')|
                                 map('split', ',') }}"

    userdata_dicts: "{{ userdata_lines[1:]|map('zip', userdata_lines.0)|
                                           map('map', 'reverse')|
                                           map('community.general.dict') }}"

    userdata_groups: "{{ userdata_dicts|groupby('Environnement') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: userdata_lines|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: userdata_dicts|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: userdata_groups|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for group in userdata_groups %}
          [{{ group.0 }}]
          {% for host in group.1|json_query(query)|unique %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        query: '[?Status == `Active`].Name'

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/hosts
        content: |
          {% for group in userdata_groups %}
          [{{ group.0 }}]
          {% for host in group.1|json_query(query)|unique %}
          {{ host }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      vars:
        query: '[?Status == `Active`].Name'
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

Comment: Many thank's, is clear :), and it works lit i want ^^